# Number of cut vertices in a graph by number of blocks

Tags: graph-theory

> If $c(B)$ denotes the number of cut vertices of a simple connected
>   graph $G$ belonging to the block $B$; prove that the number of cut
>   vertices $c(G)$ of $G$ is given by $c(G)=1+\sum (c(B)-1)$; the
>   summation being over the blocks of $G$

I'm totally stuck in this problem. I made a few examples to maybe find a reason for this and I couldn't. My only clue about it is that maybe that -1 is to compensate overcounted vertices, because a vertex is a cut vertex iff it belogns to at least 2 blocks. But I may count a vertex a bunch of times, not only twice...And that +1, I have no idea where does it comes from, it does makes sense when $G$ is itself a block...

I'd really apreciate some hints, like useful results that I can use.

Comment: I don't know it that'll help but it's the direction I'd go first.  Denote by $cuts(B)$ the set of cut vertices contained in a block $B$.

Suppose that you can order the blocks $B_1, B_2, \ldots, B_k$ so that for any $i > 1$, **exactly one** vertex $v$ in $cuts(B_i)$ was in some $B_{i'}$, $i' < i$. In other words, make it so that one $v \in cuts(B_i)$ was counted previously.

If such an ordering exists, then you can say that $c(G) = c(B_1) + \sum_{i = 2}^k c(B_i) - 1$ (the minus one for the 'already counted cut vertex').  Noting that $c(B_1) = 1 + (c(B_1) - 1)$, you get your result.

Comment: I don't think such ordering exists, because a cut vertex may belong to more than 2 blocks, let say 3 blocks $B_1,B_2,B_3$, no matter in which order I take these 3 block one the vertex was already counted twice. Or am I misunderstanding your idea? I try it in a specific graph and it didn't work because of this :/

Comment: Yes that can happen.  But, what I believe is that two blocks can have at most one vertex in common.  Say for instance that $B_1$ has cut vertices $a, b, c$,  $B_2$ has $a, d, e$ and $B_3$ has $a, c, f$.  Pick $B_1, B_2, B_3$ as your ordering.  Then $c(B_1) + (c(B_2) - 1) + (c(B_3) - 1)$ counts correctly.

Comment: That seems correct to me :) Why don't post it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote by $cuts(B)$ the set of cut vertices contained in a block $B$.

Suppose that you can order the blocks $B_1, B_2, \ldots, B_k$ so that for any $i > 1$, **exactly one** vertex $v$ in $cuts(B_i)$ was in some $B_{i'}$, $i' < i$. In other words, make it so that one $v \in cuts(B_i)$ was counted previously.

If such an ordering exists, then you can say that $c(G) = c(B_1) + \sum_{i = 2}^k c(B_i) - 1$ (the minus one for the 'already counted cut vertex').  Noting that $c(B_1) = 1 + (c(B_1) - 1)$, you get your result.

What might help in establishing that ordering is that two blocks share at most one cut vertex (probably provable by contradiction).

There's a way to find this ordering using [Block graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_graph), but it's a bit cumbersome.  Essentially,  it is based on the (unverified) premise that all members of a given clique share the same one and only cut vertex.  But let me know if you want the details.